# Can someone clarify the Archimedean property of the real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers with $x>0$, there exists a natural $n$ such that $nx>y$.

Is this basically saying that for any real number, you can find a natural number that is bigger than it?

Comment: Notice that the statement "For any real $x$, there exists a natural $n > x$" implies your statement: Since $x > 0$, we can find a natural $n > y/x$, but then $nx > y$. The simpler statement is also often called the Archimedean property and can be proved using the completeness of the reals.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite. The point is that no matter how small $x$ is and how large $y$ is, there is still a natural number $n$ that we can multiply $x$ by to "overcome" its smallness and make it larger than $y$. (Indeed, an example is $\lceil \frac{y}{x} \rceil + 1$.)

Put another way, the Archimedean property is a precise way of stating that the real numbers do not have any infinitesimal elements. If they did, then such an infinitesimal $x$ would not satisfy $nx > 1$ for any natural number $n$.

In analysis, it is sometimes good practice to regard a quantifier $\forall x$ as "no matter how bad $x$ is, this still holds", for some notion of "bad". Here there are different notions of bad: $x$ is bad when it is small while $y$ is bad when it is large.

Answer (score 3):

Sort of. Let me clarify more: think of $\Bbb R$ as a road. The Archimedean property says that given a mark in the road, $y$, and a positive distance $x$, you can always reach the mark $y$ after a finite number of "$x$" steps. For concreteness: if I give a mark on the road, say, $y = 1000$ units, and you walk in steps of $x = 0.5$ unit, then, after a finite number os steps ($n = 2001$), you will surpass the given mark.

Answer (score 0):

Archimedean property of $R$ is an illustration of the least upper bound property of $R$. This will hold for any ordered field with least upper bound property. When you take an arbitrary field, $nx$ just means doing the addition operation $n$ times. Two elements in the field are said to be infinitesimal with  respect to each other if one does not lie within a finite number of additions of the other. Archimedean property just ensures that there are no infinitesimal pairs in the field.